# How do I keyframe the position of multiple objects?

Tags: keyframes

I have several objects at different positions and I want to keyframe them all at the same time. How do I do this?

Comment: Select them all, press i and choose the kind of keyframe you want, an action will be create for each action

Comment: Hi @moonboots thanks for the help. When I press I, I don't get a pop up menu. Instead, I just get a message at the bottom that says "Successfully added 7 keyframes for keying set 'Button Keying Set'".

Comment: Go in the Timeline > Keying > Active Keying Set > Close the selected one

Comment: @moonboots thanks, that worked. 2 more related questions.

What if you want to keyframe just 1 axis for several objects, rather than all 3? Let's says I just want to keyframe the Z axis for several objects that all have different z positions.

Also, what if you want to remove the keyframes for multiple objects?

Comment: if you keyframe the location, it will keyframe both X, Y and Z, I'm not sure what you mean when you say that you only want to keyframe Z. You can delete the keyframes of several objects at the same time, just select the objects and delete the keyframes in the Timeline or in the Dopesheet

Comment: @moonboots What if I have 100 objects and I want to keyframe their Z current positions. I have to press I, select position, and then open my Dopesheet and select each of their X and Y position keyframes and delete? Is there a faster way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140940/discussion-between-kariomart-and-moonboots).

Comment: In the search field of the Dope Sheet you can type X Loc and you'll have all the X location keyframes, delete them, same for Y. Not sure there's another way (maybe a script)